# GET запрос Android Java не отправляется

Tags: java, android, http, get

Пытаюсь отправить данные серверу (чтобы он их добавил в базу данных MySQL) из Android-приложения с помощью GET-запроса.
На сервере лежит php-файлик, который этот запрос обрабатывает, он точно рабочий, если просто вбить запрос в адресную строку браузера, то всё, что нужно, в базу данных добавляется.

Отправлять пытаюсь следующим образом, отправка происходит по нажатию на кнопку:

```
public void SendToBase() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    URL url = new URL("http://mysite.ru/test.php?test=Hi&testtest=305");
                    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                    if (connection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                        MyTextView.setText("Отправлено");
                    } else {
                        MyTextView.setText("Ошибка");
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    MyTextView.setText("Исключение");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
      }).start();
    }

public void MyButton(View v) throws IOException {
SendToBase();
}
```

В итоге срабатывает исключение, судя по логам сервера, запрос просто даже не приходит туда. Разрешение на использование интернета у приложения есть. Подскажите, в чём может быть проблема

Comment: может покажете ошибку? как вариант - поможет при поиске решения :)

Comment: А где нормально посмотреть ошибку? В Logcat очень много всего и оно постоянно обновляется даже при остановке приложения, не понимаю что там копировать.

Comment: надеюсь протокол реального сервера не http? т.к. по умолчанию без разрешения в манифесте такие запросы не проходят.

Comment: К реальному серверу запросы напрямую из адресной строки пробовала отправлять и по http и по https, и так и так проходят, в базу добавляется строка. В манифесте у приложения прописаны разрешения android.permission.INTERNET и android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE

Comment: `В итоге срабатывает исключение` текст исключения?

Comment: java.io.IOException: Cleartext HTTP traffic to mysite.ru not permitted

Comment: Либо использовать https либо гуглить по этой строке и найти решение за 1 секунду.

Comment: Поставила https, всё заработало. Конечно нужно было догадаться такое попробовать) Спасибо большое!